# Como abrir uma nova View após clicar sobre um item de uma tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho uma lista de itens dentro de uma TableView
Gostaria de quando clicar em um item da lista uma nova ViewController seja aberta contendo as informaçoes referentere ao item selecionado
Não estou conseguindo fazer a view abrir utilizando o metodo abaixo:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Muro selecionado

    NSInteger linha= indexPath.row;

    Muro *c =[Muros objectAtIndex:linha];

     //navega para a tela detalhes

    DetalhesMuroViewController *detalhes = [[DetalhesMuroViewController alloc] init];

    detalhes.muro = c;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhes animated:YES];
```

o que eu estou fazendo de errado ?

Nesse link estao todos os arquivos do projeto [GaleRio](https://github.com/alexsrs/GaleRio).

Tentei usar a segunda opção e ele me retorna o seguinte erro de compilação

No visible @interface for "DetalhesMuroViewController" declares the selector "setItem"

O codigo ficou mais ou menos assim

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
DetalhesMuroViewController * detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detalhes"];

[detailViewController setItem:[Muros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas maneiras.

A primeira:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender:self];
    }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Segue"]) {
        DetalheItemViewController * itemInformationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [itemInformationViewController setItem: item];
    }
}
```

A segunda:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];        
    DetalheItemViewController * detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detalhes"];

    [detailViewController setItem:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```